# Couldn't find CB.Core version for flavor 'GeneralPublic' in version.json

Tags: source-depot

While opening pfgold source depo, I am getting below error -

> ** Warning ** Desired/Active release is unknown for package [DevConsole.Bootstrapper]
>   E:\CxCache.A\CloudBuild.OnCorext.WwXYpYMGs_mH5zBvjOHtUA\linkpackages.ps1
>   : Couldn't find CB.Core version for flavor 'GeneralPublic' in
>   version.json At line:1 char:1
>   + E:\CxCache.A\CloudBuild.OnCorext.WwXYpYMGs_mH5zBvjOHtUA\linkpackages
>   ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,linkpackages.ps1

Issue seems related to Cb.core version. But I dont know what steps to take?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the `CloudBuild.OnCorext` to version 4.0.2, which resolve my problems.
if you don't want to upgrade the `CloudBuild.OnCorext`, you can check whether the value of environment variable `CloudbuildToolsFlavor` is `GeneralPublic`. If so, you can set  `CloudbuildToolsFlavor` as `dogfood` or empty.